# "Math Processing Errors" in the Close as Duplicate Preview

Tags: bug, mathjax, review, exact-duplicates

I see plenty of "Math Processing Errors" in the close as duplicate preview:

[image]

Comment: [Probably related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18836/latex-a-jumbled-mess-when-flagging-as-a-duplicated). Usually, the Math Processing Error goes away when you choose a duplicate target. But of course their presence in the selection list doesn't make choosing easier.

Comment: You might want to include browser/OS information in this report. MathJax is rendering fine for me in that dialog (Chrome 46.0.2490.86 on Windows 8.1). Also, with respect to the (review) tag, does this only happen when you are in the close votes review queue, or does it happen when you are voting to close outside of the queue as well?

Comment: @ArthurFischer I use Firefox 42.0 Windows 7, happens only during review...